# Set Grid Columns Width=Auto and MaxWidth

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

is it possible to set a `Gridcolumn` that the behavior is like this. The `Width` is Auto but the Max is 140. In this Column there are many Labels and depending on the Userlanguage the Content changes. So I want to set a maximum Width. Like this it doesn't work:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="140"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I have a `Grid` with three `Columns`, the first and third are for `Labels`. The second is for `ComboBox`/`TextBox`. The First and second should be `Auto` so they fit the `Content` of the `Labels` and the second should fill up the remaining space.

**UPDATE Complte Code:**

```
<UserControl d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<!--</Grid>-->
<GroupBox Header="Einkauf" Height="310" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="grpLieferadresse" Grid.Column="0" Width="350" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">            
        <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                    
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="140"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Beschaffungsdauer" Name="label5" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False" Name="txtBeschaffungsdauer" Text="{Binding Path=LName1}" Margin="0,0,0,5" TabIndex="5" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Tage" Name="label10" />
        </Grid>            
    </GroupBox>
<GroupBox Header="Bankverbindung" Name="groupBox1" Grid.Column="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" Height="310">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="29"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <my:uscBankverbindung Grid.Row="1" x:Name="uscBankverbindung1" TabIndex="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>       
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

What it looks like:

As you can see the `TextBox` is very small.

[image: Column Width Problem]

Comment: You could try to set a width on your grid, the column should be cut off there.

Comment: If I do this it always stays at 140. So if none of the `labels` is longer than that there is always a blank space. That's why I would like to use `Auto`.

Comment: please explain what is not right with what you have done ?

Comment: Well if I leave it like this, if the a `Label` in the first `Columns` gets very big the second `Column` will shrink to a point where you can't see anything. If I set a `MinWidth` on the second `Column` the third `Column` will be pushed out of `View`.

Comment: well sounds like your this bit of code is right but somehow a cell(s) is asking for lotta width...  can you share whats inside the cells of column one ?

Comment: I have added a complte Example

Comment: I have edited my Code because, I set the </Grid> incorrectly in my Updateded Code. and I also add a Image to show you where the Problem is even with the updated Code from your Answer

Comment: yea, see my image it looks fine isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on my machine copy and tell me if its not right

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Header="Einkauf" Height="310" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="grpLieferadresse" Grid.Column="0" Width="350" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="140"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Beschaffusdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdngsdauer" Name="label5" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False" Name="txtBeschaffungsdauer" Text="{Binding Path=LName1}" Margin="0,0,0,5" TabIndex="5" />
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Tage" Name="label10" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Bankverbindung" Name="groupBox1" Grid.Column="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" Height="310">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="29"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
```

[image: This is what I see with my code]

Comment: It look correct. But I can't reproduce it. I copied your Code but my Result stays the same. Could you tell me what you changed?